# Selecting and displaying MS Access query results from sorted column based on other column

Tags: ms-access

I have a StudentID column, a column on passing 030 class level by a certain date, and a column on passing 040 class level by a certain date.

Can't get the two results on the same line with the ID because these refer to different classes taken at different times (some students completed 030 or 040 in a different semester so there are N / Y and Y / N results for some of the IDs.

Desired outcome: StudentID has unique values, 030 and 040 is either Y or N. All on one line for each StudentID.

Here is a screen shot of my query setup.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the current output. If an ID number has two Ys, I want them to show on the same line.

[image]

Comment: Could you please update your question with the SQL code for your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your 'Query Setup' screenshot, I can't see the foreign key that you are using with the `LEFT JOIN` from the `StudentID` field in your `152_Entrants` table, but assuming that this foreign key is also called `StudentID`, then I would suggest the following (untested) code:

```
SELECT 
    [152_Entrants].StudentID, 
    Nz(P030.PassOrFail,"N") AS 030pass, 
    Nz(P040.PassOrFail,"N") AS 040pass
FROM 
(
    152_Entrants 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, PassOrFail FROM FinalMark
        WHERE 
            SemesterNumber <= 162 AND 
            CourseType = "040" AND 
            PassOrFail = "P"
    )  AS P040 ON [152_Entrants].StudentID = P040.StudentID
)
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, PassOrFail FROM FinalMark
    WHERE 
        SemesterNumber <= 162 AND 
        CourseType = "030" AND 
        PassOrFail = "P"
) AS P030 ON [152_Entrants].StudentID = P030.StudentID;
```

Here, each of the subqueries is returning the unique set of `StudentID` values for which `PassOrFail` is `"P"` for records with `SemesterNumber <= 162` for each `CourseType`.

Your table `152_Extrants` is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to each subquery such that if a matching `StudentID` is found in the subquery, the student has passed (based on your criteria), else the student has failed and so the `Nz` function will return `"N"`.

---

#### EDIT

On viewing the composition of your `152_Entrants` query, the complete query could become:

```
SELECT 
    E152.StudentID, 
    Nz(P030.PassOrFail,"N") AS 030pass, 
    Nz(P040.PassOrFail,"N") AS 040pass
FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT StudentID FROM FinalMark
        WHERE SemesterNumber = 152
        GROUP BY StudentID
    ) AS E152
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, PassOrFail FROM FinalMark
        WHERE 
            SemesterNumber <= 162 AND 
            CourseType = "040" AND 
            PassOrFail = "P"
    ) AS P040 ON E152.StudentID = P040.StudentID
)
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, PassOrFail FROM FinalMark
    WHERE 
        SemesterNumber <= 162 AND 
        CourseType = "030" AND 
        PassOrFail = "P"
) AS P030 ON E152.StudentID = P030.StudentID;
```

Without the need for a separate `152_Entrants` query.

Comment: Result: Syntax error in query expression 152_Entrants.StudentID = P040.StudentID

Comment: @complex_holograms I have updated my above SQL code - I was missing a few square brackets required for your query name `152_Entrants`.

Comment: I really appreciate it. It works perfectly. I'll keep in mind this setup for my other queries, which work along pretty similar lines of looking at students who entered a certain course in a certain semester and then seeing how they did in another linked course in a later semester.

Comment: @complex_holograms You're most welcome. Please mark my answer as the solution if it answered your question, so that the question may be marked as resolved in order to save others time when browsing the question list.